# Get a stream of data from OpenPDC using a command line program

Tags: c#, streaming, real-time

I'm trying to use [OpenPDC](https://github.com/GridProtectionAlliance/openPDC) as a server to get data from multiple [PMUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor_measurement_unit). The machine can be Linux or Windows either.

The final goal is to be able to open a request for data of a single PMU by remote and send it to another program, using the [C37.118 protocol](https://wiki.wireshark.org/IEEE%20C37.118). Can I achieve this goal using an OpenPDC client, without using a GUI? If not, the only option to communicate with the server is using C# bindings?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is very possible. The openPDC is built on top of the [grid solutions framework](https://github.com/GridProtectionAlliance/gsf), and GSF has all the C# classes for this to work. Client applications to openPDC use the [DataSubscriber](https://github.com/GridProtectionAlliance/gsf/blob/master/Source/Libraries/GSF.TimeSeries/Transport/DataSubscriber.cs) class to get data from openPDC. You can use this same class to pull the data in which you're interested. Once you have the data, you can send it with C37.118 encoding using the [PhasorMeasurementMapper](https://github.com/GridProtectionAlliance/gsf/blob/952976a538f98baf84e3d650daf3a9a355d969b6/Source/Libraries/Adapters/PhasorProtocolAdapters/PhasorMeasurementMapper.cs) class. This kind of work is something that the openPDC and GSF are really good at. You might consider if it makes sense for your console application to create an [IaonSession](https://github.com/GridProtectionAlliance/gsf/blob/86ce7e5011cc44ff8470af194656f42cdab0d8e4/Source/Libraries/GSF.Unity/GSF.TimeSeries/Adapters/IaonSession.cs) for real-time data, just like the openPDC does. That way, you don't have to write the plumbing between the data subscriber and phasor measurement mapper. You would just be able to use the existing plumbing in openPDC and GSF.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that C# isn't the only option. You can also use the [java port](https://github.com/GridProtectionAlliance/gsf/tree/master/Source/Libraries/TimeSeriesJavaLibrary/src/org/gpa/gsf/timeseries) or the [C++ port](https://github.com/GridProtectionAlliance/gsf/tree/master/Source/Libraries/TimeSeriesPlatformLibrary).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually ended forking PMUConnectionTester and getting the already decoded data.